# I compiled an app with apktool_2.6.1 and i didn't make any changes to the app but when i run : apktool b app.apk

Tags: compilation, apk, apktool

I got the following error:

> invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\test\Documents\APK Easy Tool\1-Decompiled APKs\com.app.app2\res navigation
> brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_121707779579717501731948984067731632634.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --version-code, 4591, --version-name, 4.59.1, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL3747578255524950029.tmp, -e, C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL7131208164915828680.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\test\Documents\APK Easy Tool\1-Decompiled APKs\com.app.app2\res, -M, C:\Users\Everspin\Documents\APK Easy Tool\1-Decompiled APKs\com.app.app2\AndroidManifest.xml]

Comment: apktool fails to execute a temporary executable `C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_121707779579717501731948984067731632634.tmp`. Check your anti-virus system if it has blocked this.

Answer (score 0):

You should move to aapt2. Add `--use-aapt2` during compilation and make sure you update to a more recent version.

You can tell from the `res / navigation` error that you are rebuilding an application and that was built from aapt2 with aapt1.